# Fill ComboBox With Directory Files

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace POC1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\\");
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.AddRange(files);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I use the following code but I can't get my combobox to populate any data.  I am pretty sure I used the examples I've searched for.

Comment: can you use just `comboBox1.DataSource = files; comboBox1.DataBind();` ? Also FBD seems to be unused.

Comment: Using breakpoints, does `files` have any entries after `GetFiles` is called? Also that for loop looks questionable. `file in files` ... `AddRange(fileS)`

Comment: @ibiza I removed it now.  My bad.

Comment: You want either `comboBox1.Items.Add(file)` inside a loop, or `comboBox1.Items.AddRange(files)` without a loop.

Comment: I tried your code and had no problem.  User rights?

Comment: See the answer below about registering your Load event `this.Load += Form1_Load;`  If you didn't create this by double clicking your form, and instead copied/pasted or typed it in manually, you need this line.

Comment: @DiscipleMichael I did create by double clicking.  I don't understand why its not working on my machines as I shouldn't have any user rights issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not that it will probably make a difference but your looping through and adding all the directories for the amount of times there are directories. Should be more like

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\\");
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(file);
        }
```

or simpler

```
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\\"));
```

Also unless you have it somewhere else(been a while since ive used winforms) you need to set your form load event.

```
this.Load += Form1_Load;
```

Comment: If he double clicked the form to get this to autogenerate, he does not need to register it, it's already done.  However, if he simply copied and pasted this, then yes.  THat's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to remove the loop and have a single .AddRange(files) or, change the line inside the loop to be comboBox.Items.Add(file) as your example above is adding all files for every iteration.

It's also worth noting, when adding items, it doesn't have to be a string, but can be an object, it just needs to respond to .ToString() appropriately.

See this link, https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c7a82a6a-763e-424b-84e0-496caa9cfb4d/how-add-a-item-to-combobox?forum=winforms

Comment: You're right, it's definitely adding the entire folder contents for each file, but that alone doesn't explain his issue with nothing showing at all.