# Displaying folder contents in ComboBox/Dropdown-List

Tags: c#, windows, forms, winforms, desktop

There is a folder of "profile" files and I want the user to see and select one of those profiles in a dropdown list. The user can select one of those profiles fine, but in the dropdown list not the file names are shown, the paths to those files is shown.

The code I have so far is from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35563440/fill-combobox-with-directory-files) stackoverflow question I found online:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"[path]");

try
{
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        Profile_ComboBox.Items.Add(file);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Fehler: " + ex);
}
```

When opening the dropdown list, [path] is shown in each entry. When selecting one of the entries by clicking on it, the name of the file is shown.

I already tried using `.AddRange(files)` but I got the same results.

(Using VS Community 2019, .NET Framework 3.1)

Comment: This doesn't quite make sense to me. Is this exactly the code you are using? What is the purpose of `Directory.GetFiles(@"[path])`? What is *[path]* here?

Comment: @JonathanWood `[path]` is the placeholder I made instead of writing the full path in there because it is quite extensive

Comment: That's what I figured until you said you were getting *[path]* displayed in the list. Step through the code. What is `file` in the loop?

Comment: A string the foreach-loop is looking for in the string array `files`

Comment: That doesn't sound to me like you stepped through the code at all. And that's not what I was asking.

Comment: Can you please clearly state what the question is?

Comment: Your "question" did not contain a single question mark, so I think it is fair to ask to clearly state the question.  If you would have asked your question in a more concise way, we could have flagged it as a duplicate and you could read the tons of answers that already exist on this subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me your code shows the path of the files because the "GetFile" method returns a string array that contains the full path of the files, not only the names.

If you need only the names, in the "foreach" loop you probably need to call the Path.GetFileName method (or even better, the GetFileNameWithoutExtension)